# Application windows are behind Unity launcher in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

The programs that I open are behind the Unity launcher.

[image]

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you open "CompizConfig Settings Manager" and select "Place Windows"?

Comment: Thank you @pomsky "CompizConfig Settings Manager" and select "Place Windows" solved the problem, now works great, thanks everyone for the help!!!